# Retrieve rows based on multiple data patterns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table data:

[image]

Qns: How do I retrieve only the rows highlighted in Yellow?

Thoughts: What I did try was to do a SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C) columns and group by ID_2 column. After which, filter using a WHERE clause on B=1 OR A=1 to retrieve the records. However, I am getting also getting the first record (A23,C1) too based on the select criteria. This is what I would like to avoid retrieving.

> 1) The first criteria is always to retrieve B=1 as priority for the same ID_2.
>
> 2) The second criteria is to retrieve those with A=1 only taking into account that of the first criteria. Hence, based on ID_2, if there is a valid B=1 records that has already been retrieved, it should not retrieve twice.
>
> In this case, A34 is preferred rather than A23
>   (For instance, if based on ID_2, A or B both have 1, I would **ONLY** want 
>   the row
>   whereby B=1. In addition, A67,A89 are retrieved too.

Appreciate the help in the generation of this SELECT statement.

Comment: please tag one database ONLY.

Comment: Please elaborate on the logic for choosing those particular rows.  After all, `id_1 in ('A34', 'A67', 'A89')` trivially accomplishes what you want.

Comment: Does this question apply to mysql or Oracle?  It wouldn't apply to both.

Comment: Please explain the logic more clearly. You write twice "If based on ID_2" -- is that an error?

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you how to implement logic when you haven't explained the rules you want to enforce? I mean - why is A23 excluded by A67 included? If you can't express your rules clearly - you aren't likely to be able to code to them

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. I have updated the query accordingly. Agree with @MichaelBroughton , I have subsequently updated my rules to express what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

- Select rows with B = 1
- Select also rows with A = 1 provided that there is no other row
  for the same ID_2 that has B = 1

If so, then this can be accomplished with this SQL:

```
SELECT  ID_1, ID_2, A, B, C
FROM    tableName t1
WHERE   B = 1
    OR  (   A = 1 
        AND Not Exists (
                SELECT 1
                FROM   tableName t2
                WHERE  t1.ID_2 = t2.ID_2
                AND    B = 1)
        )
```

You can make an aggregated version as follows:

```
SELECT  ID_2, SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C)
FROM    tableName t1
WHERE   B = 1
    OR  (   A = 1 
        AND Not Exists (
                SELECT 1
                FROM   tableName t2
                WHERE  t1.ID_2 = t2.ID_2
                AND    B = 1)
        )
GROUP BY ID_2
```

Comment: @trincot..you shouldn't waste time guessing what the op thinks..let him explain what he needs